# iOS 6 game Center

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

previously to me upgrading to iOS 6, I had gamecenter working as it should. Now I cannot seem to pass achievements to the gamecenter. The achievement happens, notifies the user with an alert but says "not achieved" in the game center. I have made a sandbox account and the app has not yet been reviewed.

This is how I was previously sending an achievement to game center:

```
 [gameCenterManager submitAchievement:@"shareFacebook" percentComplete:100];
```

Is this not right anymore? I previously implemented this from the tutorial by  [mobile.tutsplus.com](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-game-center-achievements-and-leaderboards-part-2/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure your `gameCenterManager` is not `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'm doing it and seems to work well enough in iOS 6:

```
- (void) reportAchievementIdentifier: (NSString*) identifier percentComplete: (float) percent
{
    GKAchievement *achievement = [[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier: identifier];
    if (achievement)
    {
        achievement.percentComplete = percent;
        [achievement reportAchievementWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)
         {
             if (error != nil)
             {
                 NSLog(@"Error in reporting achievements: %@", error);
             }
         }];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!